# C# Timer and memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, timer

I am creating a program that will check for directory listing every 2 seconds. I expect this program to run for months without leaking memory or requiring any human interaction.

1. Below program has memory leak.
2. I am still not sure what the 10K represents.  It is not the interval.  The interval is 2k.

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer aTimer = new Timer(10000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);

        string[] DirList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TTImer");
        if (DirList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in DirList)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is garbage collected, how exactly do you have a memory leak?

Comment: So: 1. Where is the proof you have a memory leak. 2. What is "do something", because the leak is almost certain to be there.

Comment: every 2 seconds or so the memory usage is increasing

Comment: @JohnRyann That is in no way evidence that you have a memory leak.  What makes you believe that the GC won't be able to clean up that memory eventually? Are you actually getting out of memory exceptions eventually?

Comment: Unless you're calling `GC.Collect`, that isn't proof.

Comment: @DarkFalcon. the code is as is. I have not put anything in "do something"

Comment: Well, you can still leak memory/resources if you do not call dispose on disposable objects.. But If you do not have any disposable objects.. how can it leak?

Comment: @JohnRyann Then I'm confident there is no memory leak at all; this is simply expected behavior of a garbage collected environment.

Comment: btw, can anybody explain to me what the 10000 in "Timer aTimer = new Timer(10000);" represents

Comment: Also, as @Servy pointed out, you are not leaking, you are just not collecting. That's different. It may be a problem, if you keep a reference to the memory you allocate always alive, but otherwise..

Comment: @JohnRyann same as `aTimer.Interval = 10000;` you are repeating yourself there

Comment: @JohnRyann Why not check the documentation of `Timer` and see for yourself what it says?

Comment: The bigger question is why you're checking the directory every 2 seconds. If you want to know when things change, use a `FileSystemWatcher`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx. Also, I caution against using `System.Timers.Timer` because doing so can hide bugs. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/05/19/swallowing-exceptions-is-hiding-bugs/ for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, there is no memory leak, that is the expected behavior of a program in a langauge that uses a garbage collector.  The memory will increase until eventually it hits a point where the Garbage Collector cleans up any unneeded objects.
2. It's a place to specify the timer's interval.  You're overwriting it later on, so this is accomplishing nothing.

Comment: @JohnRyann You aren't "placing the garbage collection" anywhere.  You never do anything to run the garbage collection and you never need to.  It will run entirely on it's own when it feels it's appropriate, and you can feel quite confident that it will know better than you.

Comment: @JohnRyann That's simply saying that the timer should never be garbage collected.  Nothing more.  If you didn't do that the garbage collector would think that it was actually unused (as it is no longer referenced when `Main` ends) and would be freed.

Answer (score 2):

1. I am going to assume that you believe there is a *leak* because your task manager *mem usage* is going up (which is completely normal). The virtual memory manager is lazy and won't swap out anything unless it needs to. Your GC will clean up anything once a threshold is hit.
2. The 10000 value is the specified timer interval in milliseconds. As Servy pointed out, you're overwriting it later on so you're accomplishing nothing except maybe getting rid of warnings upon building the project (e.g. uninstantiated object).

Answer (score 0):

If one were being billed for every second that a megabyte of memory was being used needlessly, then it might make sense to worry about the fact that useless objects may survive quite awhile without being garbage-collected.  In practice, though, leaving memory allocated needlessly will have no effect unless or until there is some other purpose to which that memory could otherwise be put.  A typical garbage collector may be viewed as as a process that goes through a building, finds everything of value and moves it to another building, and then dynamites the first building and creates a new empty one.  The cost of that operation will depend mainly upon the amount of stuff that has to be kept, and will be largely independent of the amount of junk that gets destroyed.  Thus, unless there's something else useful that could the memory, the cost per megabyte of junk will be minimized if lots of junk is allowed to pile up before it is destroyed wholesale.  For various reasons, even if there were only one program in the system and one had four gigs of memory to run it, it would generally be a good idea to perform garbage-collection cycles before multiple gigs of junk had accumulated, but unless there are other things that need to use the memory, overly-aggressive garbage collection would impair rather than improve efficiency.