# Memory Leak in ToString

Tags: c#

I wrote an application and it was working well. I left it running for a while and then took a look and found the memory usage had dramatically increased. After a long while I have narrowed it down to a function. I started a new project with just this one function in it. When I run that I get the memory leak.

I have a timer which I start with Form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // for clock on UI
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 1000;//ticks every 1 second
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    tmr.Start();
}
```

Then I have

```
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_sync_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Which write the time to a label every second. Leave that running and you see the memory being used up I agree only in small amounts.

If I add the garbage collector I do manage to get the memory to be OK and stable.

```
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
    lbl_sync_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

I had a look on the Internet and see @ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c

I tried to use String Builder but that itself gave me problems and the memory loss is much worse.

```
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    lbl_sync_time.Text = sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).ToString();
}
```

Does anyone know how I can update the lbl_sync_time.Text without a memory loss?

Comment: why use string builder to just add a date/time stamp

Comment: There isn't any leak. Memory is used and it will eventually be collected by the GC when required. Sooner if there is some pressure, later if not.

Comment: StringBuilder wont help, you aren't doing string concatenation.  You are taking a single string and adding it to your textbox

Comment: I concur with @AdrianoRepetti, I didn't think that was possible in C#.

Comment: .Net (and windows) works a little bit different then in the old days. If there is still enough free memory in the system there won't be any clean up. Only when an application needs more memory than is currently available some clean up happens, but just enough to fullfill the applications need.

Comment: Should use `var` - `var tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();`

Comment: This could possibly help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465742/c-sharp-timer-and-memory-leak

Comment: @sαmosΛris  why use var - ive never understood why be lazy and write var?

Comment: @BugFinder in this scenario `var` is perfect.  Its absolutely clear what the type is (`new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()`).  Repeating yourself is redundant.

Comment: I come from a typecast background language, just cos 10 pages back you defined Timer x. you can then do x = new Timer().. doesnt seem wrong - and im pretty sure thats what the compiler turns it into

Comment: @BugFinder In cases where they type can be statically determined, there is no difference is using `var` or the type name explicitly. The compiler will let you know when `var` is sufficient b/c code completion will not work without an explicit cast.

Comment: @BugFinder [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) is syntactic sugar in C#, its not the same as `var` in javascript.  The sole point of var is to reduce redundant code like `System.DateTime foo = new System.DateTime();`.  With `var` you can say `var foo = System.DateTime();`.  It is still a DateTime type, no casting has to be done later on.  It just saves some typing.  There are definitely situations where `var` shouldn't be used but this is not one of them.

Comment: Please leave the `GarbageCollector` alone unless you really know what you're doing: He's usually wiser than most of us!